# add event on calendar

Tags: desktop-environments, calendar

I click on add event on calendar on right upper of screen, but it does not do anything, Do I need to do any configuration to add event using Ubuntu 13.10?

Your information and help is great appreciated,

Regards,

iccsi

Comment: You have to install a calendar application. try `sudo apt-get install evolution`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install a calendar application. For example Evolution.Install it using following command

`sudo apt-get install evolution`